# how to prevent deadlocks occurring in this SQL

Tags: t-sql, database-deadlocks

Firstly, I don't need to 100% prevent the deadlocks, but anything I can do to reduce them would be nice.

I have two tables `Source` and `Dest`. Source has a load of unique values in them, I need to request a new value from `Source` and in doing so, move it into `Dest`.

I have the following sql:

```
begin tran
    declare @value
    select top 1 @value = [value] from [source]
    delete from [Source] where [value]=@value
    insert into [Dest] ([Value]) values (@value)
    select @value
commit tran
```

this occasionally throws deadlocks when multiple users get the same `value` row. How can I prevent/reduce this?

Im using SQL Server 2008

As an aside, there are other columns in `Source` and `Dest` that I am reading from/writing to. This is a simplification for brevity.

Thanks

Comment: "when multiple users get the same value row" - your root problem is not the one you are asking about...What isolation level are you running under?

Comment: the default, so i assume thats `READ COMMITTED`

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid this race condition by using the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause your the DELETE command, since it will delete the value from source and return it in a single atomic operation. I made the following script to demonstrate the concept:

```
-- dummy data
CREATE TABLE #source (mycolumn INT);
CREATE TABLE #destination (mycolumn INT);

INSERT #source VALUES (1);
INSERT #source VALUES (2);
INSERT #source VALUES (3);
GO

-- stored procedure to demonstrate concept
CREATE PROCEDURE move
AS BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @tmp TABLE (mycolumn INT);
    DELETE TOP(1) #source OUTPUT DELETED.mycolumn INTO @tmp(mycolumn);

    INSERT #destination (mycolumn) OUTPUT INSERTED.mycolumn
    SELECT mycolumn
    FROM @tmp;

    COMMIT;
END
GO

-- testing
EXEC move;
GO -- remove from 1 from #source, insert 1 into #destination, returns 1

EXEC move;
GO -- remove from 2 from #source, insert 2 into #destination, returns 2

EXEC move;
GO -- remove from 3 from #source, insert 3 into #destination, returns 3
```

Comment: ha i just discovered `OUTPUT` - i was about to update my question to ask abouts its feasibility. +1

Comment: so presumably the `OUTPUT DELETE` is atomic/causes a rowlock that will just cause a `WAIT`?

Comment: In practical terms, this clause will not allow the same value to be returned from #source table more than once, thus avoiding the original race condition. I'm not sure how SQL Server internally implements its mechanisms, but it should not be important in this context though.

Comment: I tested this solution briefly and it still had problems; no time now will e-test later...

Comment: Can you send more information about the problems that still occur? I tested this script myself and although it worked just fine to me, maybe your actual scenarios has any detail that can be derailing the proposed solution.

Comment: Bu the way, since the `DELETE ... OUTPUT` statement avoids the race condition, If you can assume the `INSERT` command will always complete (i.e. you can guarantee all values to be inserted are valid), you could consider removing the `TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` statements at all, thus reducing the process contention inside this block.

Comment: @GerardoLima Hmm, i shall try this!

Answer (score 1):

You could grab an `XLOCK` with the `SELECT` statement

```
begin tran
    declare @value
    select top 1 @value = [value] from [source] with (XLOCK)
    delete from [Source] where [value]=@value
    insert into [Dest] ([Value]) values (@value)
    select @value
commit tran
```